# Binomial coefficient modulo a prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I cannot find a reference for the following fact: "Lep $p$ be a prime. If the binomial coefficient of $d$ over $l$ is zero modulo $p$ for every $l \in \{1,\ldots,d-1\}$ then $d$ is a power of $p$." Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Edit: I would like to thank both of you for your suggestions, but I would need a reference to put in the bibliography. Could you suggest any book or paper in which such a property is stated?

Comment: [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to ignore user10354138's comment, and prove it yourself, you will need:

- [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)
- prove that when $n$ has form $(p^r + k)$, where $k \in \{1,2,3, \cdots, [p^r - 1]\}$ that you can find at least one integer $l \in \{1,2,\cdots, [n-1]\}$ such that $p$ does not divide $\binom{n}{l}.$

One trap to avoid:

If $(ac) \equiv (bc) \pmod{p}$ and $c$ is not a multiple of $p$, then $a\equiv b \pmod{p}.$

The above implication does **not necessarily hold** when $c$ is a multiple of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x)^d -1-x^d = \sum_{l=1}^{d-1}{d\choose l} x^l$$
$p$ divides all the ${d\choose l}$ iff $$(1+x)^d -1-x^d=0\in \Bbb{F}_p[x] \tag{1}$$

Write $d= np^k$ where $p\nmid n$. From the obvious $p | {p\choose l}$ for $1\le l\le p-1$ we get by induction on $k$ that $$(1+x)^{p^k}= 1+x^{p^k}\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$$

If $d$ is not a power of $p$ then $$(1+x)^d=(1+x^{p^k})^n = 1+n x^{p^k}+ \sum_{m=2}^n{n\choose m} (x^{p^k})^m\ne 1+x^d \in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$$
Thus $(1)$ holds iff $d$ is a power of $p$.